# C# Timer not correctly responding to bool statement

Tags: c#

I feel like I am missing something here, but can't wrap my head around it.
The App should move to a different location on the screen when it switches focus to chrome instead of notepad

---

It tldr is a button to switch between apps, but once a app is minimized the button should advance to its correct position according to the open window. which is called in the `if (IsIconic(prc[0].MainWindowHandle) && isMesOpen)`

But instead moves from position when **both**  windows are minimized.

```
private void OeeCheckTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isMesOpen = false;
    foreach (Process procesjexd in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (procesjexd.MainWindowTitle.ToLower().Contains("chrome"))
        {
            isMesOpen = IsIconic(procesjexd.MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }

    //oee
    var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    if (prc.Any())
    {
        if (IsIconic(prc[0].MainWindowHandle) && isMesOpen)
        {
            var x = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 122;
            var y = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 155;
            Location = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
            IsOEE = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that

```
  isMesOpen = IsIconic(procesjexd.MainWindowHandle);
```

should be

```
  isMesOpen = true;
  break;
```